# StringIO problems when trying to create JSON response with image

Tags: python, django, json, matplotlib

I'm trying to send a JSON response in Django that includes a base64 string representation of a .png graph from python's matplotlib and some text information about it. I am running into some problems trying to convert the image to a base64 string:

```
    # Initialize objects imma need
    img_buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
    out = StringIO.StringIO()
    canvas = FigureCanvasAgg(fig)

    # Print and convert
    canvas.print_png(img_buffer)
    base64.encode(img_buffer, out)
    img_str = out.getvalue()

    # Make dictionary
    logger.info(img_str)
    resp_d = {'image': img_str, 'nodes': str(pxs)}

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resp_d), content_type='application/json')
```

Note: fig is my matplotlib `Figure()`, I've printed this directly to a response and it displayed, so I know it is being created properly.

Unfortunately, I don't get an image, and the logger shows that img_str is empty. I've looked all around and tried a few things, including using `fig.savefig(img_buffer)` instead of `canvas.print_png(img_buffer)`, but haven't had any success. I am totally stumped... any ideas what might be going on? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No luck: StringIO and cStringIO both result in an empty string.

Comment: you change from `img_str` to `img_raw_str`, is that in your original code?

Comment: Woops, typo... editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
canvas.print_png(img_buffer)
```

leaves the file pointer at the end of the "file", so `img_buffer.read()` returns an empty string.  You could call `img_buffer.seek(0)` immediately after calling `canvas.print_png(img_buffer)`, but in fact, your `out` variable is not necessary.  Instead, replace this:

```
base64.encode(img_buffer, out)
img_str = out.getvalue()
```

with:

```
img_str = base64.encodestring(img_buffer.getvalue())
```

Or, since base64.encodestring is part of the legacy interface, it might be better to use:

```
img_str = base64.b64encode(s.getvalue())
```